# R: Média de coluna pelo intervalo de valores no R

Tags: r

Fiz uma distribuição por quantis dos IDHs de todos os municípios do Brasil. A distribuição ficou da seguinte maneira:

```
 0%   25%   50%   75%  100% 
0.418 0.599 0.665 0.718 0.862
```

No meu dataframe, existe uma coluna com a porcentagem de votos que cada município deu para um determinado candidato na última eleição presidencial. Estou tentando fazer uma média dessa porcentagem considerando alguns intervalos de IDH, como por exemplo, entre 0.418 e 0.599. Tentei fazer da seguinte forma:

```
mean(votos_idhm$PERC[votos_idhm$IDHM.2010 >= 0.418 & < 0.599], na.rm=TRUE)
```

No entanto, aparece a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
Error: unexpected '<' in "mean(votos_idhm$PERC[votos_idhm$IDHM.2010 >= 0.418 & <"
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como operacionalizar isso? Desde já muito obrigado!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creio que o R não está entendendo qual variável ele precisa usar na segunda comparação. Por isso é preciso repeti-la. Usando a função which para esse caso, teríamos:

```
mean(votos_idhm$PERC[which(votos_idhm$IDHM.2010 >=0.418 & votos_idhm$IDHM.2010 < 0.599)], na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: Da maneira exata como você colocou, não foi. Mas fiz algumas alterações e funcionou bem:

mean(votos_idhm$PERC[which(votos_idhm$IDHM.2010 >=0.418 & 
                               votos_idhm$IDHM.2010 < 0.599)], na.rm=TRUE)

Muito obrigado!

Comment: Ok. Vou editar minha resposta para que não haja confusão entre futuros usuários que venham a ter a mesma dúvida.

Comment: Então. não precisa do which, basta: `mean(votos_idhm[votos_idhm[["IDHM.2010"]] >= .418 & votos_idhm[["IDHM.2010"]] < .599, "PERC"], na.rm=TRUE)`

Answer (score 4):

Suponha o banco de dados `df` e a variável `IDH`:

```
set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(
  IDH = runif(n = 100, min = .250, max = 1)
)
```

Com `tidyverse` a solução é simples:

```
df %>% 
  filter(between(x = IDH, .418, .599)) %>% 
  summarise(var = mean(IDH))

        var
1 0.5158508
```

Answer (score 2):

Boa tarde, sempre que quiser mexer com o data frame, use a função `subset(dataframe, condições)`. No primeiro argumento você inclui o dataframe que você quer retornar, pode ser ele inteiro ou indicar as colunas que você quer que retorne. No segundo argumento você coloca as condições que sejam respeitadas.

```
mean(subset(votos_idhm$PERC, votos_idhm$IDHM.2010 >=0.418 & votos_idhm$IDHM.2010 < 0.599))
```

Nesse caso ele retorna a media da coluna "PERC", onde o IDHM.2010 está entre 0.418 e 0.599. A função subset deixa o código muito mais limpo e claro que usar "which".